# Is there a fully applied curried function thunk in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Or put it another way:

Can I apply all arguments to a curried function **without evaluating it**? So I would have a function value still, and not the result of the computation?

Example:

```
add x y = x + y
add1 = add 3   {- add1 is a function -}
add2 = add1 4  {- add2 is 7, but I would like to have a function 
                  I can call with no arguments!? -}
```

The reason is to pass functions around that are fully bound and can be called in arbitrary situations and without the need to provide additional arguments.

No tricks please (like providing a bogus last argument like 1 or True at the call site).

Comment: What's the difference between your hypothetical 0-argument function and a value? How would calling that function be different from using a value?

Comment: @sepp2k The potentially expensive computation. I could make it lazy, e.g. delay it or omit it entirely if it is not needed.

Comment: Haskell is a lazy language. You don't need to make anything lazy. Everything's lazy by default unless you explicitly make it strict.

Comment: I thought at least function application was eager!?

Comment: Nope, function application certainly is not eager. `const 5 undefined = 5`.

Comment: Your `add2` is such a thunk: until you actually demand its value, `add2` will not be evaluated to `7`.

Comment: Function application **is** the thing that the statement "Haskell is a lazy language" is talking about. What would be left to be lazy if function application were eager?

Comment: @Ben I thought it referred to evaluation of function arguments, meaning that the function code decides if and when an argument value is actually forced. But I thought the code would be run right away. (But maybe that wouldn't be "lazy enough" ..)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function always takes an argument. That which does not take an argument is not a function. The only little trickery here is that some things *Haskell* considers values are, in System FC, functions. For instance `7` has type `Num a => a`, meaning that in Haskell it's a polymorphic number, but in System FC it's a function that takes a `Num a` dictionary and produces an `a`. So you kind of can have what you asked for.

However, what you asked for does not seem to be what you want! The fact that a computation is expensive does not mean you should make it the result of a function

```
x = really expensive computation
```

doesn't actually calculate `x`. Only when you *inspect* the value of `x` (by pattern matching, or `seq`, or `evaluate`, etc.) does `x` get evaluated, and even then it is only evaluated as far as necessary.

Comment:

> Ok, so GHCi betrayed me into believing that add1 4 is immediatly evaluated to 7, and this would not be the case in a normal program run?!

Nope! You typed `add1 4` at the GHCi prompt. GHCi therefore concluded that you wanted it to `print` that value. In order to `print` a number, all of the digits need to be calculated, and the number itself needs to be calculated first! If you want to peer under the hood, you can use GHCi's `:print` or `:sprint` commands, which let you inspect unevaluated or partially evaluated things.

```
Prelude> let foo = (1+2, 3+4) :: (Int, Int)
Prelude> :print foo
foo = ((_t3::Int),(_t4::Int))
Prelude> fst foo
3
Prelude> :print foo
foo = (3,(_t5::Int))
Prelude> snd foo
7
Prelude> :print foo
foo = (3,7)
```

Note: delaying things lazily has potentially bad performance implications. GHC goes to great lengths in compiled code to figure out when it can make them strict instead without affecting the meaning of the program and without causing other performance problems. This compiler pass is called "demand analysis", and it's a particular form of "strictness analysis".

Comment: Ok, so GHCi betrayed me into believing that `add1 4` is immediatly evaluated to 7, and this would not be the case in a normal program run?!

Comment: Ah, thanks, I suspected something like that after your initial answer, but wasn't sure. So I can assume that something like `add1 4` is carried around as an unevaluted expression (or so), until its value is actually required, right?!

Comment: @ThomasH, yes. The thunk will only actually do anything interesting the first time it is forced; subsequent accesses will use the stored result.

Comment: @ThomasH Showing things in ghci counts as requiring the value. Haskell promises to give you the same result regardless of when things actually end up being evaluated, so there's no way you can use normal Haskell code (even in ghci) to find out anything about when something is evaluated. That's why ghci supports non-Haskell commands like :print, so you can see what's going on under the hood.